# Send mail with image attachment from camera

Tags: ios, image, email

There are a LOT of tutorials and info about how to send attachment with your iphone / ipad app, but with pre-defined images or other file-type.
But how do i send an mail with a current file from my iphone/ipad. More specific, an image or image from camera?

Cheers and thank you

Comment: looks suspecious <!--->

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UIImagePickerController` to capture image than when you capture image :

```
  #import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h> // framework MobileCoreServices.framework

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [self sendMailWithImage:image];
    }
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

- (void)sendMailWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
     MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
     mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;         
     // make sure you can make NSData from the object
     [mailComposer addAttachmentData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"what ever you want to call the file"];
     [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Bery helpfull! I juat dont underatand the "maje sure tou can make nsdata from the inage" but i figure inhave to search that part out on the internet :)

Comment: English is apperantly not my native language :)

Answer (score 0):

```
MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
UIImage *myImage = // some code to get your image or what ever file you want
// make sure you can make NSData from the object
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToShare, 1.0) mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"what ever you want to call the file"];
[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>